regex for matching 5 digit numbers, starting with specific digits, but not allowing all repetitions
I will use JavaScript and this is the rules that I need to match:

numbers must have exactly 5 digits
numbers can only start with 1-4 and 6-9
numbers cannot have all digits repeatable

So:
12345  - match
11111  - no match (the same digit is repeated 5x
22220  - match
59876  - no match (starts with the digit 5)
90279  - match
899991 - no match (6 digits)

Here is my exploration of the regex pattern:
^(?!(\d)\1{4,})\d{5}$

The problem is that I don't know how to force it to have the first digit as [1-4,6-9].
Any help would be appreciated.

@larsks You should not include a comma in the character set. Change \d{5} to [1-46-9]\d{4} instead.

Good catch......

You could even capture the first digit and check after it that the rest of the string is not composed only from this digit: ^([1-46-9])(?!\1+$)\d{4}$

You can simply add a lookahead for starting with ^[1-46-9], if your pattern works:
(?=^[1-46-9])^(?!(\d)\1{4,})\d{5}$

or you can make the following change:
^(?!(\d)\1{4,})[1-46-9][0-9]{4}$


Yeah, you and @blhsing have nailed it! Thx
